# The script in the yii controller works, but it doesn't work through the yii console application

Tags: php, permissions, yii2, console, console-application

I have a yii controller that creating folder and downloading images in it with curl.

If I run script from browser it works like I needed, all good, but if I try to run this script from the terminal through yii console application I get this errors:
[mkdir error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5KDl.png)
[img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4qms.png)

I tried to give `chmod 777` permissions and `chown www-data` to entire project folder but it doesn't helped

Here is my functions that downloading images:

```
public function loadImg($id_tovar, $id_post, $file)
{
if (strpos($file, 'swf') === false) {

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

set_time_limit(0);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$img = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);

$err = curl_errno( $ch );

curl_close($ch);

if (@imagecreatefromstring($img) !== false) {

$source_image = imagecreatefromstring($img);

}

if (isset($source_image)) {

$exPos = strrpos($file, '.');

$type = substr($file, $exPos);

$filename = 'tov_'.$id_tovar.'_'.substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8).$type;

$dirFull = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/nal/img/'.$id_post;

if(!is_dir($dirFull)){

mkdir($dirFull);

}

$fullPath = $dirFull . '/'. $filename;

self::resizeImage($source_image, $type, $filename, $dirFull);

self::resizeImage($source_image, $type, $filename, $dirFull, 280, 280, '/l_', true);

return 'ok';

}

}

return false;

}

public static function resizeImage($source, $tip, $filename, $root, $w = 1080, $h = 1140, $pref = '/b_', $delImg = false){

$max_shir = $w;

$max_vis = $h;

$w_src = imagesx($source);

$h_src = imagesy($source);

$kw = $max_shir/$w_src;

$kh = $max_vis/$h_src;

$k = $kw;

if($kw > $kh){

$k = $kh;

}

if($k>1){

$k = 1;

}

$shir = (int)($w_src * $k);

$vis = (int)($h_src * $k);

$smesh_x = (int) (($max_shir - $shir)/2);

$smesh_y = (int) (($max_vis - $vis)/2);

$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($max_shir, $max_vis);

imageAlphaBlending($dest, false);

imageSaveAlpha($dest, true);

$color = imagecolorallocate ( $dest , 255 , 255 , 255 );

imagefill ( $dest, 0 , 0 , $color );

imagecopyresampled($dest, $source, $smesh_x, $smesh_y, 0, 0, $shir, $vis, $w_src, $h_src);

$PUTH = $root;

$name=$PUTH.$pref.$filename;

if($tip == '.jpg' || $tip == '.jpeg' || $tip == '.JPG'){

imagejpeg($dest, $name, 100);

}

if($tip == '.png'){

imagepng($dest, $name, 8);

}

if($delImg){

imagedestroy($dest);

imagedestroy($source);

}

}
```

I'm new to the programming world, so i need help of big guys. Thx a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running your script using cli instead of web server there is no document root, so `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is empty and you end up with absolute path like this `/nal/img/...` which is wrong.

You can try to use something like this to get absolute path to root folder:

```
$dirFull = dirname(__DIR__) .'/nal/img/'.$id_post;
```

Magic const `__DIR__` points to directory of current script and `dirname()` function basically gives you path one folder above path given in its argument. So you might need to modify the number of times `dirname()` function is called as needed to match your file structure.

Or you can use Yii's aliases to get correct absolute path:

```
$dirFull = \Yii::getAlias('@app/nal/img/' . $id_post);
```

Comment: omg, thank you a lot, i made it like `realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../web')`!!! You solved my problem it works now) I generally thought that the problem was access rights on linux